# Performance iText vs.PdfBox (2014)

Tags: java, performance, itext, pdfbox

I'm trying to convert a pdf (my favorite book Effective Java, if its matter)to text, i checked both iText and Apache PdfBox. I see a really big difference in performance: With iText it took 2:521, and with PdfBox: 6:117.
This if my code for PdfBOx

```
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
BUFFER.append(stripper.getText(PDDocument.load(pdf)));
```

And this is for iText

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
  BUFFER.append(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i));
}
```

My question is in what the performance depends, is there a way how to make PdfBox faster? Or only to use iText? And can you explain more about how strategies affect performance?

Comment: I agree with Elliott Frisch: I don't see a question in your post. Also note that you need to be sure that you're not comparing apples with oranges: PDFs can be constructed in many different ways. I'm not a PDFBox expert, but I wrote iText and iText has different strategies to parse PDF. Some strategies are fast, others are slow. The resulting text can also differ. In one of my assignments for the government, I wrote a benchmark using iText only and the difference in speed between strategies was more than a factor 100.

Comment: In a single file benchmark I found that the following cuts extraction time by half (2sec->1sec). PDFTextStripper.setSuppressDuplicateOverlappingText(false);
I'm not yet sure about effects it may have on accuracy.

Comment: Aside of performance keep in mind that `iTextPdf` is licensed under AGPL which can be too restrictive. The [README](https://github.com/itext/itext7) on github explicitly mentions that if you use it you should distribute your software under AGPL or use a paid license. On the other hand `PdfBox` is licensed under Apache License which suits in most cases.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> My question is in what the performance depends, is there a way how to make PdfBox faster?

One major difference is that PDFBox always processes text glyph by glyph while iText normally processes it chunk (i.e. single string parameter of text drawing operation) by chunk; that reduces the required resources in iText quite a lot. Furthermore the event oriented architecture of iText text parsing means a lower burden on resources than that of PDFBox. And PDFBox keeps information not strictly required for plain text extraction available for a longer time, costing more resources.

But the way the libraries initially load the document may also make a difference. Here you can experiment a bit, PDFBox not only offers multiple `PDDocument.load` overloads but also some `PDDocument.loadNonSeq` overloads (actually `PDDocument.loadNonSeq` reads documents correctly while `PDDocument.load` can be tricked to misinterpret PDFs). All these different variants may have different runtime behavior.

> more about how strategies affect performance?

iText brings along a simple and a more advanced text extraction strategy. The simple one assumes text in the page content stream to appear in reading order while the more advanced one sorts. By default the more advanced one is used. Thus, you probably can speed up iText even some more by using the simple strategy. PDFBox always sorts.

Comment: The remarks on the `PDDocument.load` method to use refer to the PDFBox 1.8.x architecture. Since 2.0.0 the former correct `PDDocument.loadNonSeq` has become `PDDocument.load` and the former incorrect `PDDocument.load` has been dropped.

Comment: We are required to move from iText to some other PDF API due to license constraints. What do you suggest as the best replacement of iText? Either opensource or One Time Payment for a license is also fine.

Comment: That would be a question for the software recommendation stack exchange site. When asking there, don't forget to explain your use cases. E.g. there may be different recommendations if your use case is text extraction or if it is pdf creation.

Comment: *"PDFBox always sorts."* - actually this sorting can be disabled by an appropriately named setter. The default is *on*, though.

Answer (score 1):

In the PDFBox - Version 2.0.12, they optimized the PDFunctionType3.eval() by 30%, reduced the RAM requirement of COSOutputStream, and also removed intermediate streams when merging files. All this information is provided in their release notes. Please see the link below for more information:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12343489&styleName=Html&projectId=12310760&Create=Create&atl_token=A5KQ-2QAV-T4JA-FDED%7Cddb31610c9c60486ac6cc58a5800069ddf68ccd5%7Clout

Comment: While I am happy that these changes are noticed, none of them play any role for text extraction. It is possible that other changes have improved text extraction performance since 2014, but I doubt that we're now faster than itext, assuming that the values mentioned are correct (I have not tried this myself with my copy of "Effective Java").