# Where can I download .NET version of PDFBox 2.x.x and matching IKVM binaries

Tags: pdfbox, ikvm

I have a WinForms application which uses PDFBox for extracting text from a PDF file.
The version I've been using is 1.8.4. In that version, I was using PDDocument.load, as shown below

```
public class PdfTextExtractor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Apache PDFBox classes that permit conversion
    /// of PDF documents to string.
    /// </summary>
    public static String PDFText(String PDFFilePath)
    {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(PDFFilePath);
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        string text = stripper.getText(doc);
        doc.close();
        return text;
    }
}
```

However, in the article below, I've read that PDDocument.loadNonSeq is the preferred method, and that 'Since 2.0.0 the former correct PDDocument.loadNonSeq has become PDDocument.load'

I've tried switching my code to use PDDocument.loadNonSeq, but it doesn't seem to have an overload allowing me to pass in a FilePath.

[Performance iText vs PdfBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340674/performance-itext-vs-pdfbox)

My question is this. Where can I find version **2.x.x** of *PDFBox* And matching *IKVM*?

I do not want to have to "Build" this from source. The web sites I have found that have IKVM included with PDFBox are version 1.8.9 or older.  Sites listing newer versions of PDFBox 2.x.x and up seem to be missing IKVM, which I'm reading utilizes IKVM to create a fully functioning PDF library for the .NET framework.

As the newer 'PDDocument.load' method from version 2.0.0 on are supposedly more accurate, please let me know where I can find both libraries for download.

@Tilman Hausherr. OK, if IKVM has been discontinued, then I would like to know the following:

1. Is it possible to pass a FilePath to PDDocument.loadNonSeq? If so, which of the overloads should I use?
2. Or, of the available newer .NET implementations of PDFBox i.e. 2.x.x, is there one that by itself, would have the functionality of PDF to Text conversion without the use of IKVM?

Comment: It's not available. It was never official, and IKVM has been discontinued years ago.

Comment: 1) you can use File or InputStream. That's yours to choose. 2) There is no ".NET implementations of PDFBox". PDFBox has always been a java library. IKVM somehow transforms this for .NET.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr I used your suggestion of File with loadNonSeq and it worked well. It seemed to take longer than the other method, but it also appears that the converted text is more accurate, which is important.